# Script is still running after closing pyqt5 window

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("tabletutorial.ui",self)
        self.request_function()

    
    def request_function(self):
        for i in range(0,100):
            resp=requests.get("https://www.google.com")
            print(resp.status_code)



# main
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = MainWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedHeight(850)
widget.setFixedWidth(1120)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

**This window is created by another main window.**

Now the problem is when i quit the pyqt5 window the script is still running and i am getting the status code .I am running a big application with a bunch of requests.Anyone with relatable solution please ?

I TRIED:

self.close() not worked for me. @QtCore.pyqtSlot() also not worked.

I am new to here . Please ignore mistakes and kind answer are appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the app not closing, or does it minimize without closing?

If it minimizes the app, then it's okay, then it looks like the app is working while it's being closed. Don't worry about that. Once you turn the app into an exe then this issue will (probably) fix itself.

If the app isn't closing, then it's probably because the two apps are conflicting with each other.

I have a similar issue with it, and I solved it by making a class that inherits from the main class. Here's the code for the one I used (I made the app with the designer, so it's very DRY)

This is the widget I was trying to add into the main file:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("send message")
        Form.resize(273, 376)
        self.name_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.name_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 47, 13))
        self.name_label.setObjectName("name_label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.name_label.setText(_translate("Form", "title"))
```

and then, instead of using the class as it is, you need to make a child class that does the same thing, like this:

```py
class helpUI(help.Ui_Form, QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

(`help.Ui_Form` is the original class from before)

After this you can just write `helpUi().show()` and both of them will be seen at the same time.